# Httpie how to only get response header only

Tags: httpie

In HTTPie how to get response header. When i call

```
http https://staging3.website.com Host:staging3.website.com
```

I get both header and body response. How to I get only the response header

Answer (score 6):

```sh
http --headers https://staging3.website.com Host:staging3.website.com
```

https://httpie.io/docs#output-options